# Second Mocha test not running

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I have set up an Express API with a couple of tests inside a Windows OS, the first test ran successfully inside of `wrongo/test/app_test.js`:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

describe('the express app', () => {
  it('handles a GET request to /api', done => {
   request(app).get('/api').end((err, response) => {
     assert(response.body.how === 'dee');
     done();
   });
  });
});
```

I later developed another test at `wrongo/test/controllers/users_controller_test.js`:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../app');

describe('Users controller', () => {
  it('Post to /api/users creates a new user', done => {
   request(app).post('/api/users').send({ email: 'test@test.com' }).end(() => {
     done();
   });
  });
});
```

It does not run this second test at all and I don't get my console log from `users_controller.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  greeting(req, res) {
    res.send({ how: 'dee' });
  },

  create(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send({ how: 'dee' });
  }
};
```

I don't believe I have any syntax errors, not sure why Mocha will not just run this second test.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Mocha cannot find a test if nest it within a folder within a `test/` folder, but when I moved the test file to the main `test/` folder, Mocha was able to run the test. The reason being that if you look at your `"scripts"` object inside of `package.json` there is a `--recursive` missing within:

`"test": "nodemon --exec mocha -R min"`

But I had to write the test script that way because Windows 10 kept giving me an error when I had `--recursive`.